# Compartir imagenes dentro de proyectos Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto en laravel que es un catalogo el cual guarda datos e imágenes de artículos,
ahora estoy desarrollando un sistema y posteriormente se creara una tienda en linea de la cual se van a ocupar los datos que tenemos guardados en el catalogo.

Mi pregunta, como podria acceder a las imágenes que tengo guardadas en el proyecto de catálogo desde otros proyectos de laravel ?

Obvio si le pongo la url definida por asi decirlo: 
$articulo->url =https://www.catalogox.com/images/articulo/imagen.jpg 
y esta la ocupo la mostrar la imagen si podría hacerlo
img src="{{ url($articulo->url) }}" alt="" 
¿ Existe alguna manera en que laravel comparta imágenes entre proyectos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas,

*1-puedes almacenar las rutas relativas de cada imagen en la base de datos y en la segunda aplicación configuras la conexión a múltiples DBs, y accedes a ella*

**Ejemplo para acceder:**

> config/database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [
     'mysql' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
                'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
                ]) : [],
            ],
        introducir el código aquí
    'othersDB' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
                'host' => env('DB_HOST_othersDB', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT_othersDB', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_othersDB', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_othersDB', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_othersDB', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
                'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
                ]) : [],
            ],
     (--------)  
    
    ]
```

Con esta configuración se puede acceder entre un DB y Otro y obtener los datos necesarios

Comment: Puedes apoyarte [en este link](https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/php/como-usar-multiples-bases-de-datos-en-laravel/1054453662/)